# Cannot create instance of AutConnList

Tags: c#, com, terminal-emulator

I have the following (very simple) program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The program has 'using AutConnListTypeLibrary' in the header
    AutConnList connections = new AutConnList();
    connections.Refresh();
    Debug.Print(connections.Count.ToString());
}
```

It is supposed to connect to all open PCOMM sessions, and return the number of open sessions (just to get started on something). However, when I run the program, I get the following run time error in the first line of code:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'AutConnListTypeLibrary.AutConnList'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{3CB39CC1-6F18-11D0-910D-0004AC3617E1}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I have the following references added to my project (besides the default ones):
[image: References added to the project]

Am I missing a reference? Or is there some wrong with my code? As mentioned, it is a run time error. The code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is quite a simple solution to this problem (although it's not very simple to understand). Simply add the `[STAThread]` attribute to the `Main()` method. The code from my original post should look like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The program has 'using AutConnListTypeLibrary' in the header
    AutConnList connections = new AutConnList();
    connections.Refresh();
    Debug.Print(connections.Count.ToString());
}
```